# How do I write the matrix of the orthogonal projection spanned by these two vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality

From Treil's Linear Algebra Done Wrong:

> Apply Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization to the system of vectors $(1,2,3)^T, (1, 3, 1)^T$. Write the matrix of the orthogonal projection onto $2$-dimensional subspace spanned by these vectors.

---

Using Gram-Schmidt, I found an orthogonal basis to be
$$\left\{(1,2,3), \left(\frac{2}{7}, \frac{11}{7}, -\frac{8}{7}\right)\right\}.$$

If I define the map $$T{\bf x}= \frac{({\bf x},{\bf v}_1)}{\|{\bf v}_1\|^2}{\bf v}_1+\frac{({\bf x},{\bf v}_2)}{\|{\bf v}_2\|^2}{\bf v}_2$$
and then find where the basis vectors of $\mathbb R^3$ map to, I believe can find the matrix. But this is a mess.

**Is there an easier way?**

Answer (score 2):

Faster way with $A=[v_1\, v_2]$

- $P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$

see here for the proof [Writing projection in terms of projection matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716442/writing-projection-in-terms-of-projection-matrix/2716513#2716513)

Comment: But don't we have $P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T=AA^{-1}(A^T)^{-1}A^T=I$?

Comment: @AlJebr Note that $A$ is not a square matrix.

Comment: Is is really faster?

Comment: @amd At least to write...and using matlab! ;)

Comment: Aye, when I’m not calculating by hand, I use that formula, too.

Answer (score 2):

If you rearrange your equation just a bit, you’ll have a formula for the projection matrix: $$\begin{align} \frac{({\bf x},{\bf v}_1)}{\|{\bf v}_1\|^2}{\bf v}_1+\frac{({\bf x},{\bf v}_2)}{\|{\bf v}_2\|^2}{\bf v}_2 &= {1 \over \mathbf v_1^T \mathbf v_1} \mathbf v_1^T \mathbf x\mathbf v_1 + {1 \over \mathbf v_2^T \mathbf v_2} \mathbf v_2^T \mathbf x\mathbf v_2 \\ &= {1 \over \mathbf v_1^T \mathbf v_1} \mathbf v_1\mathbf v_1^T \mathbf x + {1 \over \mathbf v_2^T \mathbf v_2} \mathbf v_2\mathbf v_2^T \mathbf x \\
&= \left({\mathbf v_1\mathbf v_1^T\over\mathbf v_1^T\mathbf v_1} + {\mathbf v_2\mathbf v_2^T\over\mathbf v_2^T\mathbf v_2}\right)\mathbf x\end{align}.$$ Each of the terms inside of the parentheses is a $3\times3$ matrix, the matrix of orthogonal projection onto the respective basis vector, in fact.

Answer (score 0):

Computing $ A ( A^T A )^{-1} A^T $ by hand in this case is really not that big of an effort.  All the entries are integers so computing $ A^T A $ is easy.  Indeed, it is a symmetric matrix, so you only have to compute 3 of its entries, and you get the fourth one for free.  Then, inverting a 2x2 matrix is easy: $ \left( \begin{array}{c c} 
\alpha_{0,0} & \alpha_{0,1} \\
\alpha_{0,1} & \alpha_{1,1}
\end{array} \right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\alpha_{0,0} \alpha_{1,1}- \alpha_{0,1}^2}
\left( \begin{array}{c c} 
\alpha_{1,1} & -\alpha_{0,1} \\
-\alpha_{0,1} & \alpha_{0,0}
\end{array} \right) $.  If you leave the fraction aside until the very end, then you can compute almost all of $ A ( A^T A)^{-1} A^T $ with integers.