# Solving Matrix equation $Y=WX$ for X

Tags: matrices, inverse, transpose

I have the following equation of matrices (3 matrices):
$Y=WX$

I know that to solve for X we have to do:
$W^{-1}Y=W^{-1}WX\xrightarrow{}W^{-1}Y=IX\xrightarrow{}X=W^{-1}Y$

But... can someone let me know how the above equation is equal to:
$X=(W^{T}W)^{-1}W^{T}Y$ ?

where $W^{T}$ is the matrix transposed and $W^{-1}$ the inverse of a matrix.

For reference, I found the following equation in page 11 of a PDF in [this hyperlink.](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/a0/f0/a0/62/3b/69/47/66/DM00119044.pdf/files/DM00119044.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00119044.pdf)

Comment: The paper linked is referring to Least Square Method, therefore in general $W$ is not square and not invertible and $W^{-1}$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
X=W^{-1}Y=W^{-1}(W^T)^{-1}W^TY=(W^{T}W)^{-1}W^{T}Y.
$$

Comment: I'm not sure your answer is correct, the paper is referring to least square method and matrix W is, in general not square and not invertible.

Comment: @gimusi I am only relaying on what the OP wrote in his question "and $W^{-1}$ the inverse of a matrix". But I believe you, that for the properly formulated question this answer may be no longer correct.

Comment: Yes indeed, if $W$ were invertible why should we calculate $$X=(W^{T}W)^{-1}W^{T}Y$$ and not by the simpler $$X=W^{-1}Y$$

Comment: @gimusi, I wish I could vote both answers as they seem correct based on my (probably wrong) question. Dietrich proves that $W^{−1}Y$ could be written as $(W^{T}W)^{-1}W^{T}Y$. But after you stating, my understanding is that the later operation is being used because we don't know if W is invertible and that is why we do not calculate the inverse of it (directly) but we do it with an intermediate calculation (transposing it, etc). As such, I think that: if $Y=WX$ then there exists a solution $X=AY$ in which the equation $A=W^{-1}$ is not necessary valid? (my math are totally weak) :(

Comment: @ekalyvio To understand what is going on you need to look deeper into the subject, refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares and https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/projections-onto-subspaces/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.2sum.pdf and  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06sc-linear-algebra-fall-2011/least-squares-determinants-and-eigenvalues/projection-matrices-and-least-squares/MIT18_06SCF11_Ses2.3sum.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As for all invertible matrices $F$, $G$ we have $(FG)^{-1}=G^{-1}F^{-1}$, it follows that $(W^T W)^{-1}=W^{-1}(W^T)^{-1}$ so $(W^T W)^{-1}W^T = W^{-1}(W^T)^{-1} W^T=W^{-1}$, and so your two expressions are the same for any invertible $W$.

Answer (score 0):

Your first solution

$$Y=WX\implies X=W^{-1}Y$$

is valid only when $W$ is a square and invertible matrix.

But in this case, as indicated in the paper, we are using the **least square method** and since in general matrix $W$ is not square we can show that the best solution is given by

$$x=(W^{T}W)^{-1}W^{T}y \implies X=(W^{T}W)^{-1}W^{T}Y$$

The matter is related to projection onto subspaces, for a detailed explanation refer to [Writing projection in terms of projection matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2716442/505767).